# if condition on node js

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm Getting confused

I tried to have to have a two condition, in the first code I'm getting `true` answer seems the answer should be `false`.

```
var a = 'route 3';
if(a === 'route 1' || 'route 2'){
  console.log('true')
}else{
  console.log('false')
}
```

on the second code, I have two conditions and the first condition it seems `true` and the second must be `false` but i'm getting `true` answer.
base on my understanding if the first condition is `false` the second condition will not be evaluated. can you enlighten my newbie mind why i'm getting `true` answered.

```
var a = 'route 1';
var b = 'route 3';

if(a === 'route 1' || 'route 2' && b === 'route 1' || 'route 2'){
  console.log('true')
}else{
  console.log('false')
}
```

thank you for the answer :)

Comment: You need to have a === 'route 2' in the second part of the condition. otherwise you are just checking if 'route 2' is a truthy value, which it is since a non empty string is always true in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this statement

`if(a === 'route 1' || 'route 2' && b === 'route 1' || 'route 2')`

the part that sais `|| 'route 2')` will always evaluate to true.

it must be `if(a === 'route 1' || (a === 'route 2' &&  b === 'route 1') || a === 'route 2')`

when you evaluate `if('route 2')` that would check for a value which always evaluates to true. You would have to compare it to something.

Comment: Thank you i used this format 'var a = 'route 1';
var b = 'route 4';

if((a === 'route 1' || a === 'route 2') &&  (b === 'route 1' || b === 'route 2')){
  console.log('true')
}else{
  console.log('false')
}

'

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Changing your first code block to this will fix your problem:

```
var a = 'route 3';
if(a === 'route 1' || a === 'route 2'){
  console.log('true')
}else{
  console.log('false')
}
```

The || operator does not work the way you think. What you are saying is: is `a` equal to `route 1`? || is `route 2`... (instead of: is a equals to route 2). The same issue applies to your second example:

```
var a = 'route 1';
var b = 'route 3';

if(a === 'route 1' || a === 'route 2' && b === 'route 1' || b === 'route 2'){
  console.log('true')
}else{
  console.log('false')
}
```

More on operators: [Javascript operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting to check if a is equal to 'route 2', when you simply do `if('route 2')`. After using `||`, you still need to explicitly define the next condition, which is a === 'route 2'.

Instead use:

```
var a = 'route 3';
if(a === 'route 1' || a === 'route 2'){
  console.log('true')
}else{
  console.log('false')
}
```

Or even more concise:

```
var a = 'route 3';
console.log(a === 'route 1' || a === 'route 2');
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem:

`'route2'` returns `true` because there is no comparing ie. `a === 'route2'` the string will always return `true`

Solution:

```
var a = 'route 3';
if(a === 'route 1' || a === 'route 2'){
  console.log('true')
}else{
  console.log('false')
}
```